# Is it true in a presentable infinity category that algebras are homotopy colimits of free algebras?

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

In 1-categorical algebra one knows that, in a locally presentable category, every algebra for a finite product theory is a colimit of free algebras. Is the same true for algebras of finite product theories in presentable $\infty$-categories? I would already be content to know this for $E_\infty$-algebras and modules over a fixed $E_\infty$-algebra in a presentable $\infty$-category. Thanks!

Comment: Going from "finite product theory" to "presentable $\infty$-category" is a vast leap. In the first place, without a fixed forgetful functor, there is no reasonable notion of "free", and even locally finitely presentable 1-categories do not come equipped with such a forgetful functor.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't note how this could be misunderstood. I wanted to know about an $\infty$-categorical version of the 1-categorical statement. I clarified the question accordingly...

Comment: I'd say this would be better asked at MathOverflow.